# How to send Post request to Authenticate the API in which session management is done by Cookies?

Tags: java, rest-assured

The REST API have session management done by cookies. In Rest Client i have the passed the following parameters in following way:

```
Body : j_username=username&j_password=password
Headers : Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
POST URL = https://websiteAddress.com/portal/j_spring_security_check
```

[Screenshot of Rest Client POST Request Sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoIgY.png)

Now, when the same request is sent through rest assured, the user is not authenticated.

Following is the code :

```
Map<String,String> headerList = new HashMap<String,String>();
                headerList.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            Response s = given().cookie("JSESSIONID", "AB52357786D65112097E554EFE4BAC77").auth()
                            .form(userName, password,
                                    FormAuthConfig.springSecurity().withLoggingEnabled(new LogConfig(captor, true)))
                            .headers(headerList).when()
                            .post("/home/mca.html");

    if (s.statusCode() == 302) {

    String location = s.then().extract().header("Location");
    //location found is index.html page i.e. 

    }
```

**HTTP Response :**

```
    HTTP Status : 302
    Date  Thu, 02 Mar 2017 14:04:49 GMT
    Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=41094D46709D0DF9AE9EDA5FE3F083D4; Path=/portal/; HttpOnly
    Location  http://websiteaddress.com/portal/index.html
    Vary  Accept-Encoding
    Content-Encoding  gzip
    Content-Length  20
    Connection  close
    Content-Type  text/html
```

Can anybody tell me how to send the same request in rest assured? I am not sure whether the user is authenticated or not.

**Note :** Cookies are managed through session management.